# Удаление элемента из двухсвязного списка

Tags: c++

Почему-то не удаляет элемент из шаблонного списка. Что подскажете делать ?

```
template<class T> void my_list<T>::Del(int x) {
    //my_list<T> *temp = new my_list<T>;
    if (x == 1 && Head->Next) {
        my_list<T> *temp = Head;
        Head = Head->Next;
        Head->Prev = NULL;
        delete temp;
        count--;
        return;
    }
    else if (x == 1 && Head == Tail) {
        Head->Next = NULL;
        Head = NULL;
        delete Head;
        count = 0;
        return;
    }

    if (x == count) {
        my_list<T> *temp = Tail;
        Tail = Tail->Prev;
        Tail->Next = NULL;
        delete temp;
        count--;
        return;
    }
}
```

> Update:

```
template<class T> my_list<T>* my_list<T>::AddFirst(T inf, my_list<T> *head) {
    my_list<T> *tmp = new my_list<T>;
    tmp->x = inf;
    tmp->Next = head;
    tmp->Prev = NULL;
    if (head != NULL)             
        head->Prev = tmp;
    count++;
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эти две строчки что делают?

```
    Head = NULL;
    delete Head;
```

---

Подсказываю: написать код, который обрабатывает случай, когда удаляется не начало и не конец, а что-то из середины списка.

Comment: Этими двумя строчками я удаляю указатель на начало. Когда в списке один элемент.

Comment: @Llor1s Не торопитесь. Посмотрите на них. Подумайте.

Comment: Извините, уже решил вопрос. Мне для задания нужно было удалить только первый или последний элементы, а я в main передавал номер среднего элемента, поэтому ничего не происходило)

Comment: @Llor1s Это то, что я Вам написал в ответе. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Можете еще подсказать с добавлением элемента вначале списка ? Вставил код выше.

Comment: @Llor1s Непонятно - это должен быть метод инстанса или статический?

Comment: Пусть будет инстенс.

Comment: @Llor1s Почему? Он же ничего не использует из объекта, на котором вызывается.

Comment: @Llor1s И почему он увеличивает `count`?

Comment: @Llor1s Какие поля есть у `my_list<T>`?

Comment: T x;
 int count;
 my_list *Head, *Tail, *Next, *Prev;

Comment: count++ ибо количество элементов увеличевается на 1.

Comment: @Llor1s Непонятно: У каждого элемента списка есть `Next` и `Prev` - это я могу представить. Но откуда у каждого элемента списка возьмутся указатели на `Head` и `Tail` - этого я пока понять не могу.

Comment: @Llor1s Увеличивается количество элементов у какого списка - который параметр или чей метод?

Comment: чей метод .....

Comment: @Llor1s А новый элемент куда добавляется?

Comment: в tmp..........

Comment: @Llor1s Проще, я думаю задать новый вопрос, в котором показать больше кода. Кажется, у Вас смешаны понятия списка и элемента списка.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058056/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0