# Добавление элемента в начало двухсвязного списка

Tags: c++

Мне нужно добавить элемент в начало списка:

```
template <class T> class my_list {
private:
    T x;
    int count;
    my_list *Head, *Tail, *Next, *Prev;
public:
    my_list() : count(0), Head(NULL), Tail(NULL) {};
    void Add(T);
    void Show();
    void Del(int);  
    my_list<T>* AddFirst(T);
    ~my_list() {
        while (Head) {
            Tail = Head->Next;
            delete Head;
            Head = Tail;
        }
    }
};

template<class T> void my_list<T>::Add(T x) {
    my_list<T> *temp = new my_list<T>;
    temp->x = x;
    temp->Next = NULL;
    count++;
    if (!Head) {
        temp->Prev = NULL;
        Head = temp;
        Tail = Head;
    }
    else {
        temp->Prev = Tail;                  
        Tail->Next = temp;                  
        Tail = temp;                        
    }
}
```

> **Update**:

```
      template<class T> void my_list<T>::AddFirst(T inf) {
    my_list<T> *tmp = new my_list<T>;
    tmp->x = inf;
    tmp->Next = Head;
    tmp->Prev = NULL;
    if (Head != NULL)             
        Head->Prev = tmp;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Я же просил показать больше кода?

Comment: Еще раз: разделите это на элемент списка и список.

Comment: Почему инициализируются `Head` и `Tail`, но не `Next` и не `Prev`?

Comment: Head и Tail - первый и последний элементы соответственно.

Comment: Про это я догадался, спасибо. Но Вы не ответили на мой вопрос.

Comment: Если нужно инициализировать - сделаю.

Comment: @Igor В строке (*List1).AddFirst(23); (*List1).Show(); выдает тот же список, без изменений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `AddFirst` не хватает строчки

```
    Head = tmp; // !!!
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо) Всего наилучшего и доброй ночи.

Comment: @Llor1s Пожалуйста. Успехов!